# Need an (Autocomplete + Mutiselect) control with checkbox using jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, autocomplete, multi-select

My client has asked for both "Multiple selection + Autocomplete" feature in a same control. Please find my sample use case below URL:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8Eqy.png

Does any of the JS Frameworks supports this feature to do multi-select with autocomplete. Please let me know. Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This plugin suits your requirements: [Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/index.html)

It has the functionality of an autocomplete and a multiple selection.

Just customize it based on your needs.

Comment: Select2 doesn't support checkboxes at all

Comment: Did I say Select2 has checkboxes? Maniram asked for a JS framework that have multiselect and autocomplete, which Select2 supports.